# Symfony 6 #[Autowire] VS #[Target] attributes

Tags: php, symfony, php-8, symfony6

From [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type), it looks like that we can use `#[Target('service_id')]` attribute in order to specify id of service to inject.

From other side, one of the new [symfony 6 features](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-service-autowiring-attributes) is `#[Autowire(service: 'service_id')]` attribute, which describes what to wire the argument to.

At first glance, `#[Target]` is just another way of doing stuff, or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If using `service_id`, than they should be acting in same way - telling to inject service that has ID `service_id`.

Difference comes when you need not service, but something different - e.g. scalar. Then you can use only `#[Autowire]` attribute:

```php
class FooClass
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Target(name: 'app.logger.on_screen')]
        private LoggerInterface $logger,
        #[Autowire(expression: 'service("App\\My\\Service").generateProxyName()')]
        private string $proxyName,
    ) {
    }
}
```

here you could not use `#[Target]`, because you do not inject service, but string value

Comment: Therefore can we always use Autowire?

Comment: @rela589n Yes, I allow you